# ¿Cómo puedo poner dos bloques de Text en la misma línea?

Tags: react-native

Resulta que tengo una vista con dos bloques de texto:

```
<View>
   <Text>Esto es un texto </Text>
   <Text>y esto otro, con otro formato</Text>
</View>
```

Lo querría ver así:

```
Esto es un texto y esto otro, con otro formato
```

Sin embargo, me aparece cada bloque en una línea diferente:

```
Esto es un texto 
y esto otro, con otro formato
```

¿Existe alguna manera de juntarlos en la misma línea? Intenté poniendo ambos `<Text>` en la misma línea pero no funcionó.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34704882/1983854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes jugar con [`flexDirection`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flexdirection), que determina el eje principal del estilo. Por defecto vale `column`, que hace que cada elemento aparezca en una línea diferente.

Si lo cambias a `row`, ¡funciona!

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <Text>Esto es un texto </Text>
   <Text>y esto otro, con otro formato</Text>
</View>
```

Información extraída de [Inline elements implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34705125/1983854)